# Resources About Playing Japanese Koto?

Tags: string-instruments

I would like to learn more about the Japanese Koto and how to play it. I just love the sound. What are good resources (books, videos, websites, …) about it in English (or German)? I watched some videos of people playing it, and found it interesting how the left hand bends strings, or the fast "trill-plucking" to get a sustained tone. But there's only so much I can understand from watching someone play. I don't have plans to buy a Koto or take lessons, for now it's "just" curiosity and interest. While I know some Japanese, it's unfortunately not enough to read a music theory book.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because finding off site resources including videos is off topic.